# Iterating LinkedList while removing elements in Java

Tags: java, iterator, linked-list

I want to do something like this:

```
int[][] A = ... // initialize matrix
List<Integer> rows = new LinkedList<Integer>();
for (int r = 0; r < 1000000; r++) rows.add(r);
Iterator<Integer> iter = rows.iterator();
for ( ; iter.hasNext(); ) {
    // some condition based on which I remove an element
    if (200 != A[iter.next().intValue()][0]) iter.remove();
}
if (rows.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("empty");
}
```

But it does not work.

Comment: What error do you get, or in what way doesn't it work?

Comment: Are you getting the infamous `DoesNotWorkException`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More than likely you are getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. This is because the value `A[iter.next().intValue()]` has exceeded the row bounds set in your `initialize matrix` section.

Assuming you do have rows, you could use:

```
for (int r = 0; r < A[0].length; r++) {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it sure works for me:

```
public class Test { 

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[][] A = new int[1000000][1];
        List<Integer> rows = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        for (int r = 0; r < 1000000; r++) rows.add(r);
        Iterator<Integer> iter = rows.iterator();
        for ( ; iter.hasNext(); ) {
            // some condition based on which I remove an element
            if (200 != A[iter.next().intValue()][0]) iter.remove();
        }
        if (rows.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("empty");
        }
    }
}
```

and prints `empty`.